# Не записываются данные в таблицу Google

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем привет.
Мой скрипт парсит "непрочитанные" входящие сообщения с почты из помеченной папки в гугл таблицу, а после помечает "как прочитанные".  Но иногда бывают сбои: скрипт выполняется, помечает письма "как прочитанные", но запись в таблицу не делает. То есть по факту получается в логгере есть запись со всем содержимым этих писем, но в таблицу они не записываются.
По идее нужно делать проверку, были ли записаны данные в таблицу и только после этого помечать письма "как прочитанные". Или же в коде ошибка, которая периодически дает о себе знать (ХЗ).
Ребят помогите, я только учусь.

```
    function GmailmarkReadEnd() {
  
  //this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //gets the right sheet(указать название листа для записи)
  
  /* searches your GMail for emails matching things "label:unread" + " label:support"
  (support-это название  папки в которую собираются письма) */
  var query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  
  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field(заменить на getBody для html) 
      var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
      
      if (query === "label:unread" + " label:support") {
        supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId]);
        Logger.log(supportStats) // Лог про который говорил.
      }
      
    }
  }
  if(!threads.length) return; //  если нет непрочитанных - ничего не делать.
  sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.
                 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet(записывает в электронную таблицу)
  
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); // помечает, как прочитанное
  
  // ***Сортировка записанных данных по дате***
  sheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  sheet.sort(4, false);
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего размер Range не совпадает с размером массива supportStats, например, массив получается 3D или  ассоциативный. Залогте размерность массива и сравните  с логом массива. + Посмотрите лог ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. На англ версии форума ребята подправили код, но потом выяснилась еще одна причина: данные в таблицу записывались по верх уже существующих. Например в таблице заполнено 10 строк и если в массиве три строки, то первые три строки в таблице заменялись на строки из массива. Вопрос решил заменив: `sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.
                 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats);` на `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats);` Позже выложу полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем привет. Спасибо, тем кто помогал. Вот окончательный вариант, с комментариями(что, да как), для таких же нубов, как я. На англ. ветке форума, можно посмотреть [подробности](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990923/data-is-not-written-to-google-spreadsheet/63995462?noredirect=1#comment113174655_63995462)

Сам код:

```
    function GmailParsing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //получаем нужный лист
  const query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; //"support"-это название  папки в которую собираются письма
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      //Здесь выбираем нужные нам поля из писем
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field((заменить на getBody для html) 
      var mId = messages[m].getId(); //поле id для создания ссылки
      supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId]);
      Logger.log(supportStats) // The log 
    }
  }
  if(!threads.length) return; //если нет непрочитанных, ничего не делать
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //запись в электронную таблицу
/*
!!!Обратите внимание!!! 
В моем примере "getLastRow()+1,2"–получаем строку +1 после последней,  2 столбик): запись идет во 2 столбик после последней заполненной строки.
*/
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); //помечаем как "прочитанное"
  sheet.sort(4, false); // сортировка по столбцу("4"-столбец, "false/true"-порядок сортировки)
}
```